# Database design relations in User and Profile

Tags: sql, database, normalization, database-relations

I'm designing a web application for a school. So far, I'm stuck with the database which has these tables:

**users**

- id
- username
- password

**profile**

- user_id (FK)
- name
- last_name
- sex
- group_id (FK)
- (other basic information)

... And other tables irrelevant now, like events, comitees, groups and so on. 
So, the users table stores basic information about the login, and the profiles table stores all the personal data about the user.

Now, the *group_id* column in the profile table has a foreign key that references the ID column of the group in which the user is currently enrolled, in the **groups** table. A user can only be enrolled in one group at once, so there's no need for any additional tables.

The thing is that it doesn't make much sense to me declaring a relation like *group* HAS MANY *profiles*. Instead, the relation should be *group* HAS MANY *users*, but then, I would have to put a *group_id* column on the **users** table, which doesn't really fit in, since the **users** table only stores auth information.

On the other side, I would like to list all the users enrolled in a group using an ORM and getting the a users collection and not profiles. The way I see it, is that the users table is like the 'parent' and the profiles table extends the users table.

The same problem would occur when setting attendances for events. Should I reference the profile as a foreign key in the events_attendance table? Or should I reference the user ID?

Of course both solutions could be implemented and work, but which of them is the best choice?

I have dug a little and found that both solutions would comply with [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), so in theory, would be correct, but I'm having a hard time designing the right way my database.

Comment: What type of group are you trying to model? Like a security authorization group? Or this guy is in the chess club group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **question of your own conventions**. You need to decide *what* is the main entity, right after that you can easiy find a proper solution. Both ways are good, but if you think of User as of the *main entity* while Profile is a *property* then you should put GroupId into User, otherwise, if you mean User and Profile as a single entity, you can leave GroupId in Profile, and by this you're not saying *group HAS MANY profiles* but *group HAS MANY users*.
By setting a proper one-to-one relation (User-Profile) you can force your data integrity good enough.